# Is saying "X allows anything to happen without any restriction" the same as saying "According to X anything can happen without any restriction"

Tags: grammar, verbs, semantics, paraphrasing, semantic-shift

I am not a native english speaker so I don't know if the below given statements have the exact same meaning. To my current understanding they do mean the same thing but I'm not sure about it.

**Statement 1**

> X allows anything to happen without any restriction

**Statement 2**

> According to X anything can happen without any restriction

So are the above 2 statements have the same semantic meaning. I mean i usually use them interchangeably and I want to know if technically using statement 2 the same as using statement 1.

##### Note

Note that in my example `X` is an `authoritative document` for example a *language specification document* etc.

Comment: The phrase _according to A_ is often used in the sense 'A has told me that this fact is true - I don't know it from my own experience'.

Comment: @KateBunting Whereas _X allows anything to happen..._ means either that a person X permits total anarchy on their premises or that a condition X removes restrictions on the behaviour of people, physical particles, physical systems or chemical processes.

Comment: @BoldBen - If X is something like a set of rules, _according to_ can mean _in accordance with_ - I was intending to point out that it could be ambiguous.

Comment: Unless X is prestigious (say the Bible), I'd resist 'X allows' as being too far distanced from 'The authority generating X'.

Comment: There is a subtle difference in meaning that is being discussed in thoughtful comments and may lead to an answer. Leave open, especially as this is a new user.

Comment: Why the downvotes? There is nothing wrong with the question. I've clearly explained the question.

Comment: This is the problem with not requiring actual sentences with actual words. "X" does not stand for a human being, and thus "X allows anything to happen without any restriction" means that X has no effect on its surroundings, which means it's abstract, since all material things interact with their environment and impose restrictions. So "X" might be _love_ or it might be _boredom_, who knows? But that was apparently not the intention of the person who hid the meaning of the subject behind "X".

Answer (score 1):

In statement 1, X is the authority who allows.

In statement 2, X has an opinion, but it is not known whether X is the authority or not.

Comment: Note that in my example `X` is an `authoritative document` for example a language specification draft etc. I've made it more clear by editing my question. So are the given two statements same?

Comment: Yes, in the light of the additional information, it can be said that the two statements are equivalent or interchangeable as has already been said by @Kate Bunting.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of the additional information that X is an authoritative document and not a person, I would say that the two statements are interchangeable.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this answer? I would like to know that.

Comment: So would I, as the writer of it!

Comment: Asking who made an anonymous move is naive. Wasn't me.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'm not asking who made the move but the reason for making it.